# How to add LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES in Window Manager Params?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-service, android-windowmanager, display-cutouts

I am creating an Android App in which I am showing a floating view on top of all apps by using a service and Window Manager. I am trying to add WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES in my Window Manager params to enable my layout to overlay with display cutouts. But it seems like this is not working in my case.

I have already tried to add it in both ways:

1. By using XML styling:

   ```
   <style name="OverlayTheme">
     <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">
       shortEdges <!-- default, shortEdges, never -->
     </item>
   </style>
   ```

   And added this style in my layout root view.
   But it does not work.
2. By using the JAVA code in my service:

   ```
   params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                               | WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES
                               | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                       PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
   ```

   It also not working. I am not sure if I am applying the Layout Params Correctly or not. Please help me to figure out the problem. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

This is the way I had implemented my the bubble in my service:

1. Initialized Window Manager and Layout in onCreate() method:

   ```
   windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   if (inflater != null)  mLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null, false);
   ```
2. Added this view to window by Window Manager:

   ```
   WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
   params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                               | WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES
                               | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                       PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
   ```
3. Finally added this view to Window by addView Method:

   ```
   windowManager.addView(mLayout, params);
   ```

   By using the above methods I am able to show my view on top of other apps. But the problem is that my view is not not overlapping with a display cutout. This is happening when android is in landscape mode.

**Solution:**

I solved this by just adding this line of code (As suggested in Answere):

```
     params.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try setting in your `Activity`:

```
window.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am currently in service and not in any activity and I am setting my views on top of other apps (like a bubble) by using WindowManager.LayoutParams params and windowManager.addView(mLayout, params); method. I have updated the method in my Question so that you can better understand. As I have no reference for the window variable, I can't implement it like this. Tell me if I am wrong somewhere...

Comment: Thank you so much. I managed to do it by setting params.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES; as suggested by you and it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much for finding this! I want to add a caveat here that I was only able to get this working once I set the flag via this method  programmatically (`layoutInDisplayCutoutMode` -- not via the `setFlags` parameter) _before_ adding the view to the window.  Thank you!!!